# How to reload after success google login

Tags: javascript

This is my code, when i try to use window.location.reload(true); in onSuccess() function then, it reload the page every seconds, please help me how do i reload it only once.

```
<script>

function renderButton() {
gapi.signin2.render('gSignIn', {
    'scope': 'profile email',
    'width': 240,
    'height': 50,
    'longtitle': true,
    'theme': 'dark',
    'onsuccess': onSuccess,
    'onfailure': onFailure
});
}


 function onSuccess(googleUser) {

gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function () {
    var request = gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get({
        'userId': 'me'
    });
    request.execute(function (resp) {
        // Display the user details
        var profileHTML = '<h3>Welcome</h3>';
        document.getElementsByClassName("userContent")[0].innerHTML = profileHTML;
        
        document.getElementById("gSignIn").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementsByClassName("userContent")[0].style.display = "block";
    
    // Save user data
        //saveUserData(resp);
    });
    
});
 }

  // Sign-in failure callback
    function onFailure(error) {
    alert(error);
     }
</script>
```

Comment: what is you goal? reloading the page is not recommended. you are stuck in a loop

Comment: I just want to reload that page through which i can start the session in the website